# Get list of monetized fields in money-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

Is there a way to get an array of money fields defined with monetize?

I need them for some metaprogramming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your model is `Monetizable`, does this work?

```
MyModel.monetized_attributes
```

Comment: Great, it returns a hash of the money names and the underlying cents db column